# What is the significance of "it did" at the end of a sentence?

Tags: relative-clauses

Nevertheless, such a generalisation does not take us far towards an understanding of why the revolution broke out when it did, and why it took the remarkable road **it did.**

---

I wonder why the last words "it did" was put at the end of this sentence?
Is it for emphasis? Then, is this regularly used for emphasis?

Comment: Without "it did" (or "that it did") one is left wondering what "road" is being discussed.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, comprehension is impaired without it. Unlike in the expression used much by the Northern Irish *My car broke down, so it did*. In that example the last three words are completely unnecessary - except in Belfast, for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have expected,

> *Nevertheless, such a generalisation does not take us far towards an understanding of why the revolution broke out when it did, and why it took the remarkable road **that** it did.*

This can be paraphrased with the somewhat redundant sentence:

> *Nevertheless, such a generalisation does not take us far towards an understanding of why the revolution broke out when it did, and why it took the remarkable road **that** it took.*

The sense is that there were many roads that it could have taken, some remarkable, some not. It emphasises the particular road that it took and that this road was remarkable.  There is also a deliberate echo of 'it did' from the previous clause.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Does "It" mean "the revolution"?

Comment: Yes, the revolution took a remarkable road.   This means that that the revolution developed in a remarkable way.  ("way" == "road")

Comment: @anotherworld The first "it" means "the revolution", the second one means "the road".

Comment: @WS2: I don't think the second "it" refers to "road".

Comment: @Sankarane Apologies. You are correct - both "its" refer to the revolution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of style.

"Nevertheless, such a generalisation does not take us far towards an understanding of why the revolution broke out when it did, and why it took the remarkable road it did."

Let me reproduce the later part of the sentence and rephrase it so we may take a closer look:

"... why the revolution broke out when *it broke out*, and why it took the remarkable road *it took*."

The writer chooses to use the verb "to do", thus replacing the italicized *verbs*, ending up with "it did", which is possible.

Examples:

I don't know why John acts the way *he does* at parties.
Do you think you understand why his behavior changed abruptly, the way *it did*?